# Can not login into cloned Joomla! 3.2 site

Tags: php, joomla

I have a local installation of Joomla! 3.2.0 (for editing and testing) and clone that to a commercial server (for publishing) as described in http://docs.joomla.org/Copying_a_Joomla_website using ssh and MySQL CLI. The only files that are NOT copied are .htacces and configuration.php.

The front end works very nicely, all content is displayed correctly, however, no user can login at the backend (/administrator): "Warning - Username and password do not match or you do not have an account yet."

I can see all users in the database of the server where login fails. Are there any PHP settings or values in configuration.php to look out for? How to approach this?

Thanks!

Comment: Check your DB connection settings, do you use correct DB and server?

Comment: @BaBL86: I guess so, otherwise the front end would not work, would it?

Comment: Not a 100% true. Frontend can work with cache or another db requisites in current config or with sqlite, for example.

Comment: @BaBL86: I have just changed some content in the _content table of the DB and it is reflected in the front end, so I guess it is not the cache. Why could Joomla! be using another database to access the back end than the front end?

Comment: Hmm.. can you create a new user and try to login?

Comment: @BaBL86: Can I create the password hash with $md5pass? Do I need a salt for that?

Comment: No, I want you to use Joomla Registration Form component. If you have not this on the site, try to add via administrator in a local copy and then put to the server.

Comment: Check secret and pwsecret properties in config, it may help you. They must be identical on your copies (restore from your local)

Comment: @BaBL86: $secret is identical for both, but there is no $pwsecret for either of them ...

Comment: What happens if you copy the sites to a subdirectory on your localhost and duplicate the database. Try doing that and seeing if you can login. It might possibly be a server related issue in regards to sessions

Comment: Ok, what I have done now is: (1) Create a new instance of Joomla! 3.2.0 from the application package provided by the hoster directly on the server. (2) Created a user. (3) Copied the password hash from this new user to a user on the cloned instance I can not log in at. (4) Log in with that password - IT WORKS. Would anyone mind explaining that to me?! (The $secret in configuration.php are different, by the way!)

Comment: WHat php versions do you have on the two sites? ALso can you check what the prefix of the passwords is?

Comment: @Elin: locally php 5.4.6, password starts with $2y$...; remotely php 5.3.3, passwords are in kind of a ... : ... format except the one set by the hosters configurator which starts with {SHA256}.

Comment: So what's happening is that the one site does not support bcrypt and is falling back to Sha256.  THis is because 5.3.3 is old.  There's a bug in the sha24 handling, but what you can do is go in and set both sites to use weak passwords and change the passwords on the old site to salted md5 and them move those up to the other site.  Also I think that the next release will fix the bug.

Comment: @Elin - ahh yes I remember George telling me about this with PHP versions below 5.3.x (forgot to last digit). Good reminder ;)

Answer (score 1):

If before cloning the PHP version on your server was >= 5.3.7
and if on another server you have version less than mentioned above in this case joomla process password in different way.

**The solution is:
change the password-hash in table  #__users to MD5 of password you wish to use.**

Comment: I was banging my head to solve this issue, your answer fixed my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your configuration.php has a value that needs to be copied from dev to production, it's "secret" and it's used to hash passwords. If this is not there, that's the reason.

Another possibility is that you have accidentally enabled the two factor authentication, but I'd go with the first option 99% should solve your issue.

**Update**

Joomla 3.2.1.rc just released, try that first!

Additionally:

Joomla plugin twofactorauth and the option to use stronger encryption doesn't properly set defaults when upgrading. Thus you might get away with forcing the params, but I don't have code for that (it's up to you).

Link to the Joomla article ["How do you recover or reset your admin password?"](http://docs.joomla.org/How_do_you_recover_or_reset_your_admin_password) 
but it's not appropriate in 3.2, still it may work.

Finally, a code solution was published [here](http://alterbrains.com/blog/100-joomla-3-2-passwords-issue-problem-solution)

Comment: Thanks ... however,as explained about $secret is the same for both. The issue is obviously different encryption algorithms, as suggested by @Elin.

Comment: but Elin didn't post here. Also, the encryption algo is only one, with the other being the new "Strong security". I added a link with the emergency login procedure from Joomla.org in my answer.